# Embed Audio Files in a visualforce Page in a secure Way

Tags: visualforce, callout, authentication

I am in process of submitted a salesforce app which has a close integration with third party app developed by someother guy. Integration include basic authentication i.e user name password in header of requests.

Issue:

One of api callout return public links of audio files in json i.e

```
[
  {
    "file1": "https://login.example.com.au/media/audio/file1.wav"
  },
  {
    "file2": "https://login.example.com.au/media/audio/file2.wav"
  },
  {
    "file3": "https://login.example.com.au/media/audio/file3.wav"
  }
]
```

who are rendered on the visualforce page using html5 audio tags. but Salesforce guys asked us to secure them instead of keeping them publicly accessible. Putting Auth token in GET is not an option. I need suggestions to be implemented on both sides.

Comment: Are the files publicly accessible?

Comment: Yes files are publicly accessible. Thats the issue. Salesforce guys dont want them to be publicly accessible. I can have the Webservice modified to accept auth header and return the body of file in response but do you think that's doable to have it embedded in HTML audio tag.

Comment: As per my knowledge, the only way to secure media files is via streaming. Even somebody can record the streams also, but it is better than the direct files.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide music and video to your consumers in different ways. In addition to letting consumers download digital media files, you can also stream them. Streaming content is a good choice when you want to make it available but you do not want to give copies of it to consumers. Streaming also forces consumers back to your Web site to play your digital media files, which is advantageous when you want to make sure that consumers see branding, advertisements, and other information on your site.

However, streaming digital media files rather than providing them for download does not necessarily ensure that the files are secure. Several programs are currently available that allow a consumer to capture an audio or video stream and save it to a file on their computer. Consumers can then play the resulting digital media file at any time and share it with other people. To ensure that your audio and video content is secure and protected, package your digital media files first, and then stream them.

Source: - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb649410(v=vs.85).aspx